# Wrapper for converting std::string to QString?

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

I have `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` defined so I cannot cast from a `char*` to a `QString`. Previously I've been using: `QLatin1String`
But I just noticed `QString::fromStdString`, I don't like using this because `QLatin1String` is preferred to `QString::fromLatin1`.

Does anyone know of a Qt object for `std::string`s that works like `QLatin1String`?

Comment: `QLatin1String` is just wrapper around `const char *` c-string. So I have no idea what you want. Do you want convert to `QString`? Or do you what just `QLatin1String`.

Comment: @MarekR `QLatin1String` is to `char*` as `?` is to `std::string`. I wanna know what the `?` is.

Comment: There is no Qt object that matches `?`. The official method for converting std::string to QString is `QString::fromStdString()`. What do you mean by "`QLatin1String` is preferred to `QString::fromLatin1`"?

Comment: It would be best if you paste here code you have and code you want to have. Note: you are making common mistake asking how to fix your solution of some problem instead describe the problem you are trying to solve. Final outcome is that we have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: @JKSH I guess, there isn't a wrapper for this is the official answer then. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it; with much disappointment. As far as QLatin1String being preferred, check here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlatin1string.html#details

Comment: How is `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` relevant? It just forces you to be explicit, instead of having implicit default. If you want the behavior you would have without it, read from docs what happens then and use the right explicit method. If you want `QString`, create `QString`. If not, consider just keeping your `std::string`, nothing wrong with that in Qt code, it's C++...

Comment: @hyde `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` forces you to use Qt's thin wrappers: `QLatin1String` for `const char*`. The relevance to this is that I want a thin wrapper for `std::string`s so I don't have to call `c_str` before using Qt's wrapper.

Comment: @JonathanMee I've read the link, but I still don't really understand why you don't like using `QString::fromStdString()`. Is it for efficiency, to avoid creating copies? Like Marek R said, please edit your question and explain: What are you trying to do? Why do you need these wrappers? If you explain that clearly, maybe we can find an even better solution.

Comment: @JKSH I've written up an answer which summarizes the problem and cites your statement that there isn't a wrapper for `std::strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who use Qt with `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` enabled `char*`s and `std::strings` cannot be assigned to a `QString` or cast to a `QString`.

This will not compile with `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` enabled:

```
QString foo( "Hello World" );
```

You could do this but [Qt frowns upon it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlatin1string.html#details) because it creates, "temporary `QString` objects and make a deep copy of the character data":

```
QString foo( QString::fromLatin1( "Hello World" ) );
```

Instead you have to use:

```
QString foo( QLatin1String( "Hello World" ) );
```

It's a little more frustrating if you need to get a `QString` from a `std::string` because you have to now call:

```
QString foo( QLatin1String( helloWorld.c_str() ) );
```

There is a direct conversion but not with Qt's recommended wrappers:

```
QString foo( QString::fromStdString( helloWorld ) );
```

That is to say I have not been able to find a wrapper for `std::string` and [JKSH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144539/jksh) [asserts that there isn't one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631925/wrapper-for-converting-stdstring-to-qstring#comment36312926_23631925). So I believe that as of Qt 5.2 the preferred solution is to use the `QLatin1String` wrapper.



(As an aside for those interested in multilingual software, Qt's `QLatin1String` and `QString::fromLaint1` both expect the `char*` to be in proper unicode; `QString::fromStdString` actually uses `QString::fromUtf8` under the hood to convert to proper unicode.)

Comment: using conversion from std::string more efficient to provide size:
`QString foo(QLatin1String(helloWorld.c_str(),  helloWorld.size()));`

Comment: @Oleg I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment?